# how does one translate "smoking meat"?

Tags: traducción, verbos, comida

I was trying to express, "I smoked some pork spare ribs this past weekend," in Spanish.

I tried looking up smoking meats in the Spanish dictionary and often I get `fumar` (to smoke), `asar` (bbq), or `ahumar`. Which of the aforementioned verbs are used in reference to smoking meat?

What is the correct way to say "to smoke meat"? Is there a correct verb that translates that more correctly?

Answer (score 5):

The correct word is [**ahumar** in its 3rd entry.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?val=ahumar) For instance:

> Un ahumador experimentado sabe cómo ahumar costillas de cerdo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto es 'Carne ahumada', 'Yo ahumé carne ayer.' Conversationally, it is usually something you made: 'Hice una carne ahumada ayer.'

Carne asada is grilled or braised meat.

Carne fumada would imply you lit it on fire and inhaled the smoke.

Comment: Claro que no. "Carne ahumada" no significa "smoking meat" sino "smoked meat".

Comment: Tranquilo, @Michael Wolf, el conjugar lo dejé al OP. Lo importante de la pregunta era el vocabulario.

Answer (score 0):

The correct translation of what you were trying to express: "I smoked some pork spare ribs this past weekend" to Spanish would be "Yo ahumé unas costillitas de cerdo el fin de semana pasado."
Whomever mentioned that: "...smoking meat is not the same as smoked meat..." is not realizing that the "smoking" in your sentence is a verb.  It is what makes the finished product of "smoked meat" to which he is referring. Since, in your sentence, the "smoking"results in the "smoked meat".
It is not the same as "smoking" a cigarette which would be "fumando" I am smoking a cigarette is: "[yo] or [me] estoy fumando un cigarillo."
It is matter of correctly conjugating the verb "ahumar."
Just for fun. please note that: "Yo ahumé un cigarillo means I "smoked" a cigarette--but in the way you "smoke" meat and not in the way you "smoke" a cigarette.