# Smoking foods terms

Tags: traducción, comida

I'm looking for a definitive answer for the word "to smoke (food)", to BBQ, and the word for "Smoker" (again for food).  Here in Panama we call smoked chicken "Pollo a la Leña."

Comment: See also [How does one translate “smoking meat”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12025/5481) for the difference between `ahumar`, `fumar` and `asar`.

Answer (score 7):

The *[ahumado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahumado)*, from [ahumar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1KIQXuu):

> 2. tr. Someter al humo algún alimento para su conservación o para comunicarle cierto sabor.

is

> una técnica de conservación alimenticia que consiste en someter alimentos a una fuente de humo proveniente de fuegos realizados de maderas de poco nivel de resina. Este proceso, además de dar sabores ahumados sirve como conservador alargando el tiempo de conservación de los alimentos.

(Same for the English version of the Wiki page - Not a direct transalation)

> Smoking is the process of flavoring, browning, cooking, or preserving food by exposing it to smoke from burning or smoldering material, most often wood.

The "ahumador"is the place where the food undergoes the smoking process, but it is also the name in Spanish for the person preparing/preserving food this way.

Comment: Ha sido para mí un placer otorgarte el voto que te ha hecho alcanzar los 25000 puntos. ¡Enhorabuena por este logro! :-)

Comment: The place where food is smoked is also known as _ahumadero_.

Comment: @JMVanPelt, ni "ahumador' ni 'ahumadero' aparecen en el DRAE (si bien "ahumadero" tiene entrada en wikcionario...) Al _googlear_ los dos términos me salen un buen puñado de entradas para cada uno. Será una diferencia regional? A ver si alguien aporta más respuesta y completan o resuelven esta duda.

Answer (score 5):

Literally "to smoke" is "[ahumar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1KIQXuu)", and the smoker is "el ahumador"

There are other 2 verbs related to smoke something:

- [sahumar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wzvspdl): to smoke with perfumed smoke (not only food)
- [humear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ko2w945): in someplaces a "humeador" is a bee smoker

Comment: Hola motilio: ¿podrías proveer algo más de información? En [answer] se explica bien, pero básicamente es bueno poner ejemplos, referencias oficiales, etc. Es decir, todo aquello que pueda ayudar a mejorar la comprensión del tema.

Comment: claro, fue respuesta rápida desde el celular, pero veo que Diego ya puso una respuesta más detallada.

Comment: Igualmente seguro que puedes aportar información para que la respuesta sea una digna competidora de la de Diego :)

Comment: creo que la respuesta de Diego es muy completa, de todas maneras la complementaré :)

Comment: ¡Gracias por mejorarla! Me permití añadir enlaces al DLE a cada una de tus recomendaciones. No recordaba _sahumar_... bonita palabra.